# Unittests MagicMock doesn't return value on call

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I wonder why my code doesn't work properly:

```
class UtilsUnittests(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        # Mock LinearMetricsClient
        self.patcher_metrics_client = patch('src.utils.Client')
        self.mock_metrics_client = self.patcher_metrics_client.start()
        self.mock_metrics_client.create = MagicMock(return_value=(200,{}))

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.patcher_metrics_client.stop()

    def test_get_report_data__successful(self):
        data = get_report_data(arg_1, arg_2)
```

On call it will raise:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

On call it return just MagicMock object instead of the `200, {}`

`utils.py` file:

```
from external_lib.http_clients import Client

def get_report_data(report_query_params, obj_id):
    metrics_client = Client(obj_id)

    code, response_body = metrics_client.create(report_query_params, '/search')
    response_body = json.loads(response_body)
    ...
```

When I print output of `metrics_client.create(report_query_params, '/search')` it returns: `___<MagicMock name='Client().create()' id='4337409232'>`

Structure is

```
|- src
|--- src/utils.py
|- tests
|--- tests/test_main.py
```

Comment: You are patching the method on the class instead of the instance. You need something like `self.mock_metrics_client.return_value.create = ...` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mrBeanBremen suggested, I have changed the code a little to return_value logic:

```
    class UtilsUnittests(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        # Mock LinearMetricsClient
        self.patcher_metrics_client = patch('src.utils.Client')
        self.mock_metrics_client = self.patcher_metrics_client.start()
        self.mock_metrics_client.return_value.create.return_value = MagicMock(return_value=(200,{}))

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.patcher_metrics_client.stop()

    def test_get_report_data__successful(self):
        data = get_report_data(arg_1, arg_2)
```